# Firefox: contenteditable is not editable if it's nested inside draggable parent

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I have this [simple html](https://jsfiddle.net/dL7ug4pm/):

```
<div draggable=true>
  <div contenteditable=true>can't edit me</div>
</div>
```

In Chrome, I can edit the contents of contenteditable, but I can't do that in Firefox and IE. Is this some known issue? Why does Chrome allow editing? Any existing workarounds?

Comment: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/479

Comment: @IsmailFarooq, no, this is a different case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the click handling for the `draggable` element conflicts with the `contenteditable` handling - both require you to click, so which handler should be used?

There are a couple of options you could take. The version below disables `draggable` when you click, so as to allow the user to focus on the editable content, and then enables it if you double click instead:

```
<div class="content">
  <span>Edit and drag me</span>
</div>

$(".content").draggable()
  .click(function() {
    $(this).draggable({ disabled: false });
}).dblclick(function() {
    $(this).draggable({ disabled: true });
});
```

Alternatively, there is a good solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6603190/1814840) which involves setting the `handle` property of `draggable` to an outer element via a class selector, which is positioned with CSS. This is probably a nicer solution than hacking around with click events, but it depends on your usage.

**Update**
I have added a slightly modified version of the solution I linked to above [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dL7ug4pm/3/). You can edit the text as well as drag the whole thing via the handle icon.

Comment: thanks, I'd appreciate if you showed it for my situation as it's a bit different than the one in the link you provided

Comment: I see now, thanks. It's not using native draggable functionality of a browser. I'm wondering if there is any way to implement similar approach with native functionality?

Comment: we're using [angular dndlist](http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/types) directive so there's already a similar functionality there too